# Como posso passar esse trecho de código para localstorage?

Tags: php, javascript, html, geolocalização

```
<script>

   navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
      document.cookie = "mylat="+position.coords.latitude;
      document.cookie = "mylng="+position.coords.longitude;

})


var mylat = Number("<?php print_r($_COOKIE['mylat']); ?>");
var mylong = Number("<?php print_r($_COOKIE['mylng']); ?>");


var myLatLng = {lat: mylat , lng: mylong};
```

Comment: Nesse trecho de código vejo que você tenta pegar a geolocalização do usuário mas antes define uma última posição encontrada. Você deseja gravar essa última posição? O que exatamente você quer gravar no localStorage?

Comment: Eu desejo armazenar a posição atual do usuário para depois definir os estabelecimentos de interesse dele. Consegui fazer o local storage, mas quando subo no servidor ftp ele mostra que estou no meio o mar, ou seja... a latitude e longitude estão nulas ou zeradas.

Comment: Onde você está utilizando localstorage exatamente? no código que você postou só com cookies

Answer (score 0):

Você deve perceber código em javascript é assíncrono e que, principalmente, o tipo de requisição de geolocalização que você está fazendo da localização do usuário utiliza um callback, portanto

```
function(position) {
    document.cookie = "mylat="+position.coords.latitude;
    document.cookie = "mylng="+position.coords.longitude;
}
```

Está sendo executado depois de

```
var mylat = Number("<?php print_r($_COOKIE['mylat']); ?>");
var mylong = Number("<?php print_r($_COOKIE['mylng']); ?>");
```

Então, provavelmente você está conseguindo uma posição apenas na segunda execução em diante. Além de estar sobrescrevendo a variável `document.cookie` apenas com a longitude.

Para utilizar localStorage você pode utilizar

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
  // esta função é executada apenas depois de conseguir a localização
  // o que pode acontecer depois do script fora desta função

  var coords = position.coords; // apenas para encurtar
  localStorage.setItem("mylat", coords.latitude); // gravar lat
  localStorage.setItem("mylng", coords.longitude); // gravar lng
  // mudar centro do mapa
  map.setCenter({lat: position.coords, lng: position.coords});
})

// posição padrão em caso de não existir última posição gravada
var defaultLocation = {lat: -9.919302, lng: -50.486085};


var mylat = localStorage.getItem("mylat")
if (mylat === null) { // em caso de não existir lat gravada
  mylat = defaultLocation.lng; // use a lat da localização padrão
}

var mylng = localStorage.getItem("mylng");
if (mylng === null) { // em caso de não existir lng gravada
  mylng = defaultLocation.lng; // use a lng da localização padrão
}

var myLatLng = {lat: mylat , lng: mylng};

// Assumindo que você está usando um mapa da Google Maps Javascript API em map:
map.setCenter(myLatLng);
```